# pypsark randn with mean and variance

Tags: std, mean, normal-distribution, generate

I would like to generate numbers from Normal distribution. I used this line to do so:

```
df1 = sqlContext.range(0, 1000000)\
 .withColumn('normal',func.round(randn(seed=23),2))
```

So I assume normal column does that with mean `0` and std `1`.

**Is there a way to generate these numbers with `mean=10` and `std=5` for example?**